# Procedure if a football player, when sent off, refuses to leave the pitch

Tags: rules, football, officiating

What would happen when a player, after being shown the red card, refuses to leave the pitch?

Comment: Arrested for trespassing?

Comment: The reason I'm voting to close this older question, is because the newer question has attracted answers with more up-to-date information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [FIFA Laws of the Game 2013/2014](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/footballdevelopment/technicalsupport/refereeing/laws-of-the-game/), a player that has been sent off the field is considered an **outside agent**:

> **Outside agents**
>   Anyone not indicated on the team list as a player, substitute or team official is 
>   deemed to be an outside agent, as is a player who has been sent off.
>
> If an outside agent enters the field of play:
>   •  the referee must stop play (although not immediately if the outside agent 
>   does not interfere with play)
>   •  the referee must have him removed from the field of play and its immediate 
>   surroundings
>   •  if the referee stops the match, he must restart play with a dropped ball 
>   from the position of the ball when the match was stopped, unless play was 
>   stopped inside the goal area, in which case the referee drops the ball on 
>   the goal area line parallel to the goal line at the point nearest to where the 
>   ball was located when play was stopped

In November 2009, amateur footballer Paul Cooper was given a red card and refused to leave, yelling and arguing with the referee.  The referee showed him a second red card, and he still refused to leave.  Cooper ended up getting shown the red card 6 times over a period of 5 minutes before he left the game, and play continued.  The Scottish Amateur Football Association banned him from football for two years and fined his team £150.  ([Source](http://www.dailyrecord.co.uk/news/scottish-news/footballer-picks-up-world-record-1050870)).

Comment: 6 red cards in 5 mins has to be some kind of record!

Comment: A player can only be sent-off once in a match, so I'm pretty confused as to why the referee thought it was correct procedure to continue showing the red card. Furthermore, given this was an amateur match, it's mind-boggling that the referee didn't abandon the game after two minutes, let alone after five minutes of a sent-off player refusing to leave the field.